# Hovering one item should activate all item with the same class

Tags: html, css, class, hover

I've got a class - let's call it `.purple` and I got several items with this class

```
<img src="..." class="switch_purple">

<p class="purple"> Purple</p>
<p class="purple"> Purple</p>
<p class="green"> Green</p>
<p class="purple"> Purple</p>
<p class="green"> Green</p>
<p class="purple"> Purple</p>
```

What I want to do is, **without using Javascript**:

- Hovering an item with `.purple` class will hover all of the same class
- Hovering the image with `.switch_purple` will hover all of the `.purple` class

---

[Update] First way worked:

```
.purple:hover ~ .purple, .purple:hover {...}
```

Problem: Only takes effect to all next items.

Comment: use css pseudoclass :hover

Comment: @Sai No, that won't work, since :hover only works when you hover over a parent element. He's trying to use :hover for peers and non-family elements.. YOu can't do this with just CSS... but you can with jQuery

Comment: Without javascript, I cannot think of a way to do this.  You can add CSS to define how the items will look like when hovered.  You would need a scripting language to actually cause the hovering effect on items that the user is not interacting with.

Comment: @Sai but how... .purple:hover only let the hovered item take effect. But not the other - that's what I want to do... hover one item and all get the effect

Comment: ohhh im really sorry i didn't see you mentioned all the selectors with purple classes. It cannot be done using CSS alone.

Comment: @user3342174 why aren't you using javascript for that? Maybe I can tell you how to evade the reason...

Answer (score 0):

Without javascript the closest thing you can achieve is something like this using the **general sibling combinator selector**: http://jsfiddle.net/6gEC8/

```
.switch_purple:hover ~ .purple,
.purple:hover,
.purple:hover ~ .purple {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The problem is that only `p`'s after the hovered element get the effect...

Comment: Based on your requirements, this is the closest you can have without using javascript...

Comment: @user3342174 please check this if it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

... Or you would need to use jQuery. But if you can accomplish the same thing with CSS, I'd go that route.

```
// find .switch_purple, apply hover event
$('.switch_purple').hover(function(){

    // toggle .active class
    $('.purple').toggleClass('active');

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ggjRG/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with CSS only, using the ~ (sibling) selector.  It will select any p elements with class "purple, as long as they follow the img.

```
.switch_purple {width: 50%; height: auto;}
.purple:hover,
.switch_purple:hover ~ p.purple {
  color: purple;
}
```

See here the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z59tq/3/